# surface temperature due to constant heat flux

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conduction, convection

Imagine a hollow cylinder with the outside surface exposed to air (convection). If there is a constant heat flux on the inside surface how would I calculate both the inside and outside surface temperature?

Comment: Temperature will stabilise when power in is equal to the heat lost to the surroundings. I think you will find that calculation is quite complex.

Comment: @Transistor Pretty much the case with every "How do I calculate the temperature?" question.

Comment: Buy a book for ME's for the heat transfer class and work through it until you get to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The steady-state [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) is $\nabla^2 T=0$, where $\nabla^2$ is the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator). In the axisymmetric 2-D case, $T=T(r)$ and [$\nabla^2 T=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial T(r)}{\partial r}\right)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Two_dimensions), where $r$ is the radial distance. From
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial T(r)}{\partial r}\right)=0,$$
multiply by $r$ and integrate to obtain
$$r\frac{\partial T(r)}{\partial r}=C_1\Longrightarrow \frac{\partial T(r)}{\partial r}=-\frac{Q}{2\pi rk},$$
where I've plugged in the heat-flux boundary condition of $Q$ (in watts per cylinder length in meters, corresponding to a heat flux of $q=Q/2\pi r_1$) and denoted the annulus thermal conductivity by $k$. Integrate again:
$$T(r)=-\frac{Q}{2\pi k}\ln r+C_2.$$
The convective boundary condition at the outer radius $r_2$ for convective coefficient $h$ and ambient temperature $T_\infty$ is
$$Q=2\pi r_2 h[T(r_2)-T_\infty].$$
Solve for $C_2$ to obtain
$$T(r)=-\frac{Q}{2\pi k}\ln\left(\frac{r}{r_2}\right)+\frac{Q}{2\pi r_2 h}+T_\infty.$$